# UI Image size scales on canvas of Unity 2d

Tags: canvas, unity-game-engine

When I place a UI image on a canvas in Unity 2d the size of the image will scale according to the screen size of the device. Is there any way to keep the size of the image unchanged like a sprite?

When using an image it scales differently in the editor to the device. How do I keep the size consistent?

Comment: Try set pivot of image is middle center in inspector.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the **UI Image Scale** the same with the screen resolution...

[image: Pivot]

...as shown by the image, make sure that the pivot is not on **stretched** *(the one with arrows)*